# ffmpeg encoding sample wanted?

Tags: c++, c, video, encoding, ffmpeg

I found [this tutorial about ffmpeg](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) the thing i do not get is how to encode video.

can any one, please provide a tutorial.. with explanations for that? (not that i dont get this official [one](http://www.squashedfrog.net/mythtv/devdocs/api-example_8c-source.html) but i'd love to see more comments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FFmpeg's developers guide [refers to](http://ffmpeg.org/developer.html#SEC2) an [api sample](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-example_8c-source.html) featuring encoding and decoding of both audio and video. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410459/encode-audio-to-aac-with-libavcodec/2968867#2968867) links to it as well.