# Passing a native fd int to FFMPEG from openable URI

Tags: android, ffmpeg, storage-access-framework

I am trying to open a file descriptor from a `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` URI from the Storage Access Framework. I am first trying with a file on the sdcard, which I can already resolve to a file path using the `_data` column and open (I am trying to get away from doing this, and use the file descriptor instead).

I get the the native int fd like this:

```
int fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r").detachFd();
```

Then in C++, I am trying to open it like this, the idea taken from [How to properly pass an asset FileDescriptor to FFmpeg using JNI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701029/how-to-properly-pass-an-asset-filedescriptor-to-ffmpeg-using-jni-in-android):

```
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
pFormatCtx->iformat = av_find_input_format("mp3");

char path[50];
sprintf(path, "pipe:%d", fd);

int e;
if(e=(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,path,NULL,NULL)!=0)){
    av_strerror(e, path, 50);
    return error;
}
```

This yields an "Unknown error" from `avformat_open_input`. The same thing happens if I use the jni method `jniGetFDFromFileDescriptor` from the above linked on a `FileDescriptor` object to get the int fd instead. How can I open an openable URI with FFMPEG correctly without using the file path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701029/how-to-properly-pass-an-asset-filedescriptor-to-ffmpeg-using-jni-in-android   looks similar

Comment: @RobertRowntree I linked it in my question already, that's what I based what I tried to do on.

Comment: @SteveM as per https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavu__error.html#ga4ebaa288c7684a26a591c501208910e4 the error is generated from supporting libraries. You might wanna take a look at the source code to figure out which library is causing the error

Comment: @DipenShah This is the only useful information so far - I think the error is because I built it without the pipe protocol.

Comment: Build without `pipe` is definitely a good cause for the problem. But using `pipe:` for many formats is not good enough, because ffmpeg does not enable seek for this protocol, and some formats need seek for correct read and/or write. To work correctly with files that come from [SAF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage-access-framework), I [have defined](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/pull/440) a custom `saf:` protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My project ([FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/)) accomplishes this. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wseemann/b1694cbef5689ca2a4ded5064eb91750#file-ffmpeg_mediametadataretriever-c) or the [full file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/master/gradle/fmmr-library/library/src/main/jni/metadata/ffmpeg_mediametadataretriever.c) here.

**Note**: make sure you have built FFmpeg with the pipe protocol enabled!

I used `avformat_open_input`, `dup()` the file descriptor and made sure to set the offset via:

```
 if (state->offset > 0) {
        state->pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
        state->pFormatCtx->skip_initial_bytes = state->offset;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Steve M, may be you got your answer from these posts: such as : 
1. [ffmpeg encoding sample wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269614/ffmpeg-encoding-sample-wanted)

and finally you explore this project .
https://github.com/illuusio/ffmpeg-example

Best of luck! @Stev M

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a silly observation, but did you try to replace:

avformat_open_input(&avFormatPtr, "dummyFilename", nullptr, nullptr);

```
(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,path,NULL,NULL)
```

Replace for:

```
(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,path,nullptr,nullptr)
```

?

Comment: ffmpeg libraries are pure C, and calling them from pure C (which does not have a notion of **nullptr**) is entirely legitimate.