# FFMPEG Reading audio from memory doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libav, libavformat

When I try to instantiate this struct, my program crashes:

```cpp
struct MemoryAVFormat {
    MemoryAVFormat(const MemoryAVFormat &) = delete;

    AVFormatContext *ctx;
    AVIOContext *ioCtx;

    MemoryAVFormat(char *audio, size_t audio_length) :
            ctx(avformat_alloc_context()),
            ioCtx(create_audio_buffer_io_context(audio, audio_length)) {

        if (ctx == nullptr)
            throw audio_processing_exception("Failed to allocate context");

        if (ioCtx == nullptr)
            throw audio_processing_exception("Failed to allocate IO context for audio buffer");

        ctx->pb = ioCtx;
        ctx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;

        int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, "nullptr", NULL, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            throwAvError("Error configuring context from audio buffer", err);
    }

    AVIOContext *create_audio_buffer_io_context(char *audio, size_t audio_length) const {
        return avio_alloc_context(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(audio),
                                  audio_length,
                                  0,
                                  audio,
                                  [](void *, uint8_t *, int buf_size) { return buf_size; },
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL);
    }

    ~MemoryAVFormat() {
        av_free(ioCtx);
        avformat_close_input(&ctx);
    }
}
```

I've read and tried every single tutorial on doing this and none of them work

Has anyone got this working before?

crashes on the line: `int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, "nullptr", NULL, NULL);`

Comment: "Trying to instantiate this struct fails:" - what do you mean ? Does it give errors at compile time ? at runtime ?

Comment: @Programmer The app crashes

Comment: I'll try and show the stack trace, but its all machine code - I don't understand it

Comment: @Programmer does that help?

Comment: Oof, i do not know how to understand this, sorry .... But i think it might have to do something with passing `nullptr` as arguments in `int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);` ...

Comment: @Programmer its normal to pass in Nulls

Comment: @HTNW look at the tutorials. people either pass null filename or a "DUMMYNAME". The API gets the audio from the `ctx->pb`. Hence the flag: `AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO`

Comment: @HTNW If you look at the documentation, there's even an old example doing this - but didn't work. All the posts on SO don't work

Comment: i know by now, i just read the docs...

Answer (score 2):

`avio_alloc_context()` documentation specifies that `buffer` parameter should be allocated by `av_malloc()` and moreover it will be released by `AVIOContext` destructor and can be reallocated at any time:

```
 * @param buffer Memory block for input/output operations via AVIOContext.
 *        The buffer must be allocated with av_malloc() and friends.
 *        It may be freed and replaced with a new buffer by libavformat.
 *        AVIOContext.buffer holds the buffer currently in use,
 *        which must be later freed with av_free().
```

In your code sample you omit details of allocation of `audio` buffer, but I suppose that it doesn't meet these requirements, so that crash happens when FFmpeg tries to release or reallocate `audio` buffer.

I guess passing an entire audio file content as an externally allocated buffer wouldn't work with `AVIOContext` - this API is really meant to be used with a temporary buffer for streaming data from somewhere else (file, web or another memory buffer).

I don't have a complete sample to see if it will work as expected, but code might look like this (you will probably need to tune `read()` function and consider implementing [seeking procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445600/ffmpeg-seeking-not-possible-with-file-descriptor-on-android-q/60702386#60702386) as well):

```
struct MemoryAVFormat {
    MemoryAVFormat(const MemoryAVFormat &) = delete;

    AVFormatContext *ctx;
    AVIOContext *ioCtx;

    char *audio;
    size_t audio_length;
    size_t audio_offset;

    MemoryAVFormat(char *theAudio, size_t theAudioLength)
    : ctx(avformat_alloc_context()),
      ioCtx(nullptr),
      audio(theAudio),
      audio_length(theAudioLength),
      audio_offset(0) {
        ioCtx = create_audio_buffer_io_context();
        if (ctx == nullptr)
            throw audio_processing_exception("Failed to allocate context");

        if (ioCtx == nullptr)
            throw audio_processing_exception("Failed to allocate IO context for audio buffer");

        ctx->pb = ioCtx;
        ctx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;

        int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, "nullptr", NULL, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            throwAvError("Error configuring context from audio buffer", err);
    }

    int read (uint8_t* theBuf, int theBufSize) {
        int aNbRead = std::min (int(audio_length - audio_offset), theBufSize);
        if(aNbRead == 0) { return AVERROR_EOF; }
        memcpy(theBuf, audio + audio_offset, aNbRead);
        audio_offset += aNbRead;
        return aNbRead;
    }

    int64_t seek(int64_t offset, int whence) {
         if (whence == AVSEEK_SIZE) { return audio_length; }
         audio_offset = offset;

         if(audio == NULL || audio_length == 0) { return -1; }
         if     (whence == SEEK_SET) { audio_offset = offset; }
         else if(whence == SEEK_CUR) { audio_offset += offset; }
         else if(whence == SEEK_END) { audio_offset = audio_length + offset; }

         //if(audio_offset < 0) { audio_offset  = 0; } else
         //if(audio_offset > audio_length) { audio_offset = audio_length; }
         return offset;
    }

    AVIOContext *create_audio_buffer_io_context() {
        const int aBufferSize = 4096;
        unsigned char* aBufferIO = (unsigned char* )av_malloc(aBufferSize + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
        return avio_alloc_context(aBufferIO,
                                  aBufferSize,
                                  0,
                                  this,
                                  [](void* opaque, uint8_t* buf, int bufSize)
                                  { return ((MemoryAVFormat* )opaque)->read(buf, bufSize); },
                                  NULL,
                                  [](void* opaque, int64_t offset, int whence)
                                  { return ((MemoryAVFormat* )opaque)->seek(offset, whence); });
    }

    ~MemoryAVFormat() {
        av_free(ioCtx);
        avformat_close_input(&ctx);
    }
}
```

An alternative to implementing `AVIOContext` interface and using `avformat_open_input()` could be passing an audio buffer as a payload of a custom `AVPacket` directly to decoder, if you know in advance in which audio format your stream is (e.g. by skipping creation of `AVFormatContext` at all). I did this for decoding image pixmaps, but don't know if it could be (easily) applied to audio.

Comment: Im getting an error for overallocating an array for the audio_stream (I thought because the AV read was corrupted) but in reality only the `AVStream::duration` property was corrupted. What I don't understand is why this property is only corrupted when using customIO? And can I obtain the stream length in another way?

Comment: Maybe this is not because it is a custom IO, but because it is unseekable?

Comment: Is that what you were saying with: `(you will probably need to tune read() function and consider implementing seeking procedure as well)`?

Comment: Implemented `inline auto read(uint8_t *theBuf, int theBufSize) {
        int read_count = std::min(int(audio_length - audio_offset), theBufSize);
        if (read_count == 0) { return AVERROR_EOF; }
        std::memcpy(theBuf, audio + audio_offset, read_count);
        audio_offset += read_count;
        return read_count;
    }

    inline int64_t seek(int64_t offset, int whence) {
        if (whence == AVSEEK_SIZE) return audio_length;
        audio_offset = offset;
        return offset;
    }` and it worked. Thank you very much, I looked everywhere for this stuff!

Comment: Yes, that's what I've meant. I've put seek() function to the answer for completeness.