# FFmpeg How to write video to a file

Tags: c, ffmpeg

What i want is

```
 1. Get video packet from stream source
 2. Decode it
 3. And write  that decoded data as video file(avi, mpeg etc)
```

I can able to get video Packets from a file (as AVPacket) and also can decode and save as an image.(raw)( FFmpeg tutorials show how to do it).
**But i can not** ( do not know ) **write that video data to a file**(other) which can be played by media players(such as VLC).

Best Wishes

Ps: Real code samples will be great if possible...

Now i make test with **av_interleaved_write**  but i got strange error "non monotone timestamps" ( i have no control over pts values of media source )

**Some Extra Info**

In FFmpeg I have to

1. Read media packets from media source ( it may be real file(.avi,mov) or even rtsp server).
2. Then write those media packets to a real file (physical .avi, .mov etc file)

I need reader and writer. I can read the media source file ( even encode packets according to given format). But i can not write to  file...(which any player  can play)

And some pseudoCode

```
File myFile("MyTestFile.avi");

while ( source ->hasVideoPackets)
{
     packet = source->GetNextVideoPacket();
     Frame decodedFrame = Decode(packet);
     VideoPacket encodedPacket = Encode( decodedFrame);
     myFile.WriteFile(encodedPacket);
 }
```

Or Just write the original file without encode decode

```
     File myFile("MyTestFile.avi");

     while ( source ->hasVideoPackets)
     {
         packet = source->GetNextVideoPacket();
         myFile.WriteFile(packet);
     }
```

Then

```
I can able to open MyTest.avi file with a player.
```

Comment: Bounty Award to the person that provides a link to an good example which implements this. using av_interleaved_write_frame or av_write_frame

Comment: check this link which demonstrates the writing video file using FFMPEG libs : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077

Answer (score 2):

Now there's a new example of video transcoding in **doc/examples/transcoding.c** of FFmpeg trunk, and it does exactly what you need: [API example for demuxing, decoding, filtering, encoding and muxing.](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html)

This is for the current **ffmpeg 2.4.4**

Answer (score 0):

you need to write an  encoder to convert raw data to required video format

> [ffmpeg encoding sample wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269614/ffmpeg-encoding-sample-wanted)
>
> [Encode audio to aac with libavcodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410459/encode-audio-to-aac-with-libavcodec/2968867#2968867)

Comment: I can encode and decode data using ffmpeg library( not cli, use api). What i can not do  is write to actual file using av_interleaved_write  function so that any player can play it.(sure player has neccessary codecs).

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this at some point using libx264 and vorbis.

A code example.
https://github.com/Themaister/SSNES/blob/master/record/ffemu.c

The basic idea is that you have to set timestamps yourself in the `AVFrame` when you want to encode it. Then you can take that packet and write it with `av_interleaved_write()`.

Comment: Well, i can not figure out how to to tell "av_interleaved_write_frame" function write packets to which physical file( such as read packets and write to "mytest.avi" file.

Comment: Well i figure out. ctx->oformat = av_guess_format(NULL, ctx->filename, NULL); But since i have one source file and destination file, should i have to create 2 AVFormatContext : one for reading and one for writing?

Comment: It looks like the repo has vanished off the net.  Searching for the filename found https://blog.naver.com/p4violet/120150852154.