# How to extract video clips using the LibVLC API?

Tags: libvlc

My question is exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681855/how-to-extract-audio-video-clips-using-the-libvlc-api-or-ffmpeg-api), except that... is it possible to achieve the goal with LibVLC? Thanks!

By the way, are there any full-fledged tutorials or books for LibVLC? There are plenty modules mentioned in [this page](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/modules.html), but without a tutorial it's difficult/impossible for me to understand how they work. So far, the only tutorial I found is https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/ which is very primitive and says nothing about demuxing, decoding, encoding or muxing. Any information or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: LibVLC for Android uses ffmpeg internally. As per my knowledge extracting video clips feature is not exposed as any LIBVLC API.

Comment: @Jickson Thanks for the reply, Jickson. I already knew that ffmpeg is the final boss lurking behind the shadow. Many libraries and media players use it, including GStreamer, mpv, etc. I did have read some tutorials of ffmpeg. IMO, it's not convenient to use. It goes into too much details. I'd rather stick with LibVLC or GStreamer, especially LibVLC, because GStreamer depends on Glib, which I'm not familiar with. Anyway, thanks for the reply.