# Encode loopback capture data in mp3 using ffmpeg in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to work on loopback capture(What you hear) and record this file in mp3/aac format using VC++.
->I can capture audio and can create a .wav file i.e. not compressed but I want a compressed file so I'm encoding this through ffmpeg to write an mp3 file not a .wav.

However I'm not getting any way to do it directly?
I referred [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx) for loopback capture.

Please share your experience and opinions.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not getting any way to do it directly"?

Comment: I mean I want to create an mp3 or aac file from raw data. but using ffmpeg I'm not getting how can I do it?

Comment: Could it be you are doing it wrong? Show your code, check similar questions: [Encode audio to AAC with libavcodec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410459/encode-audio-to-aac-with-libavcodec)

Comment: This is how I'm writing a .wav file and this is pretty good [link](http://snk.to/f-ch3qz2wl) for ffmpeg use I'm trying to write in this way with a [link](http://snk.to/f-c7nlr0qi) with no result.

Comment: Excuse for the code as I'm a beginner.